# Apache Solr Search Results

Tags: search

The apache solr search results object doesn't seem to be indexing one of the fields I've added, a field with the machine name of field_resource_type.

How do I add this? Is it in a configuration file?

The actual content type (resource) is being indexed, and several fields inside of resource are being indexed.

How do I index this one field?

Comment: What kind of field is it? Have you tried clearing the index/cache and re-indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Typically text based fields are automatically added to the Solr index, as a convenience feature. It is up to the site builder to exclude fields. One reason the field may not appear in the index could be it's data type, but if it's a standard field type (shipped with Core) then there is something much simpler incorrectly setup (or it's just not indexed itself yet).